# Unit testing method with SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, code-coverage, lightning-connect

I'm currently updating a lot of my unit tests to get a healthy average above 75% for some wiggle room.  The controller I am currently testing on has a SOQL query within the method I am testing.

```
try {
     List<PreferredConstituentInfos__x> pis = [select 
         consType__c,
         constituent_id__c,
         title__c,
         first_name__c,
         middle_name__c,
         ........                  
         phoneType__c
     from
         PreferredConstituentInfos__x
     where
         constituent_id__c = :currCase.ConstituentID__c];
```

Within my unit test I am trying to force fake values into this query when the test runs.  That way it will go within the next if statement:

```
if (pis.size() == 1) {
```

Does this require a mock method within the test class? Or is there a way to inject the values into the controller during the test run? I'm pretty new to test classes and I inherited this code I'm trying to test. So trying to see the whole picture and write unit test from scratch is challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the equivalent of a call-out, a mock would seem to be appropriate since you're going through the Salesforce Connect adaptor. For that reason, this could also be considered an asynchronous operation.

Using a CSV file, you'd need to insert the data, so that wouldn't seem to help unless your object was writable (you didn't say). I'd recommend mocking it as going through a connector.